# How 'minOccurs' and 'maxOccurs' attribute value will generated inside the `element` tag of the WSDL file?

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, apache-axis

We have custom java code that deployed in the `JBoss`. We are firing the webservice call and the `WSDL` file is generating by using the `Apache Axis` framework.

My question is for some of the tag, `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` attribute is present, but for some other tag, those attributes are not present.

If I want `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` attribute inside the element tag, then where I have to configure? How this `Apache Axis` framework will generate these attribute.

**Sample WSDL :**

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" 
xmlns:impl="urn:sif.siperian.com" xmlns:intf="urn:sif.siperian.com" 
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
targetNamespace="urn:sif.siperian.com">
<!--
WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.3
Built on Oct 05, 2005 (05:23:37 EDT)
-->
<wsdl:types>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="urn:sif.siperian.com">
<complexType name="Account">
<sequence>
<element name="accountNumber" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="accountType" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="cardholderName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="city" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="expirationMonth" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="expirationYear" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="hubStateInd" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="issuingCompany" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="pkeySrcObject" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="postalCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="rowidObject" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="securityCode" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="source" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="stateProvince" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
<element name="streetName" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>

<complexType name="ArrayOfAccount">
<sequence>
<element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="item" 
type="impl:Account"/>
</sequence>
</complexType>

</schema>
</wsdl:types>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

In the above WSDL, the `<complexType name="Account">` is not having property `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs`.

Where as, the `<complexType name="ArrayOfAccount">` is having both the properties.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a Java Code sample on how to build the following element:

```
<element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Test" nillable="true" type="xsd:string"/>
```

Java Code:

```
elemField = new org.apache.axis.description.ElementDesc();
elemField.setFieldName("test");
elemField.setXmlName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.test.com", "Test"));
elemField.setXmlType(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "string"));
elemField.setMinOccurs(0);
elemField.setNillable(true);
```

Hope this helps.